# Get unique rows with tolerance, matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the matrix

```
mat_=[1    1.25; 
      2    1.75;
      3    1.49; % Should be deleted as (abs(1.25-1.49)<.25) 
      4    1; 
      5    0.9; %(abs(1-.9)<.25)
      6    2.05];
```

I want to get a matrix with unique value and tolerance (e.g., `tolerance=0.25`). I made this matrix `mat_unique` manually just to explain my point

```
mat_unique=[1 1.25; 2 1.75; 4 1 ;6 2.05];
```

Any idea??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach -

```
tol=0.25 %// tolerance
mat_unique = mat_(~any(triu(abs(bsxfun(@minus,mat_(:,2),mat_(:,2).'))<tol,1)),:)
```

Comment: `bsxfun` with `triu`, way to go

Comment: @LuisMendo Made sense that way and you didn't notice the `.'`, did you? :)

Comment: Hahaha. No, I didn't. I would give you another +1 for that if I could :-)